# "Let's just say" expression clarification

Tags: contractions

I am wondering what the **'s** in the `let's just say...` expression is.

Is it "let us just say"?

I doubt it is the *to be* verb, because it doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: *Let's* always means *let us*. As a native speaker, I cannot construct a single example where it means *let is*. (According to my dictionary, *let* can be a noun sometimes, meaning "hindrance" or "a foul in the game of tennis" but I've never heard either of those meanings until I looked it up just now.)

Comment: Well, that's not a *to be* verb. "Let is just say." isn't just right. Anyways, welcome to ELL!

Comment: @apsillers Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: [let's](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/let-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's* always means *let us*. As a native speaker, I cannot construct a single example where it means *let is*. *Let* is a verb, so *let is* does not make sense.

The correct meaning of the phrase is, "Let us just say..."

(According to my dictionary, *let* can be a noun sometimes, meaning "hindrance" or "a foul in the game of tennis" but I've never heard either of those meanings until I looked it up just now. Here, and virtually everywhere, *let* is a verb.)

Comment: "The apartment I am offering to let is on Jackson Street.  I'll meet you there at noon"  ...